# QGIS 2.6.1 doesn't load python plugins on Ubuntu after upgrade

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, ubuntu

I have experienced this scenario once before and now today, whenever I updated my QGIS installation on Ubuntu, it didn't reload python plugins under ~/.qgis2/python/plugins when started, only c++  plugins are available. I can't really recall what I did previously but when I restarted my machine it seemed to work out of the box. Any ideas?

Comment: qgis 6.2.1 needs python 2.7 - which python do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using pythin 2.7.3

Comment: are there any error messages on startup

Comment: Nope. QGIS starts okay. But it doesn't load or show python plugins only c++ plugins. This started after an update, but before it was just working fine. I was able to use python plugins. I experience the same before, I can't really remember how I sorted the issue out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126673/qgis-install-on-ubuntu-14-04-fails You need to install the python packages for QGIS manually in a second run.

Answer (score 2):

AndreJ is right. When I did an upgrade of QGIS from version 2.6.0 to 2.6.1, python-qgis was not upgraded in the process and was held back at version 2.6.0. This I confirmed by running dpkg below.

`dpkg -s python-qgis`

After manually upgrading python-qgis as suggested by AndreJ.

`sudo apt-get install python-qgis`

QGIS finally was able to reload python plugins.