# QGIS 2.12 & Ubuntu 14.04 SAGA installation not found

Tags: ubuntu, saga, qgis-2.12

Installing `QGIS 2.12` on `Ubuntu 14.04` from the `debian trusty` ppa. Upon opening QGIS I notice the following error under the `Processing` tab:

```
Problem with SAGA installation: SAGA was not found 
or is not correctly installed
```

If I execute `sudo apt-get install saga` I then get that the version installed (2.1) is unsupported.

I did make sure to "properly" purge QGIS before installing as in [QGIS install on Ubuntu 14.04 fails](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126697/36886)

Looking inside `~/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/algs` folder it does seem like SAGA is installed... but how to get QGIS to recognize it?

Comment: Processing that comes with QGIS as part of the python-qgis-common package is in ```/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs```

Comment: by  ```debian trusty``` did you mean the  ```http://qgis.org/debian```. If you want newer SAGA use ```http://qgis.org/ubuntugis/``` and ```apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable```

Comment: Yes. I don't necessarily want *newer* SAGA, just **functional**

Comment: After purging `qgis`, changing `ppa` to `ubuntugis` and then installing again. No luck. After manually running `apt-get install saga`, the warning goes away.
**However**, the source of this initial problem `QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'` when trying to create a buffer still happens... (which appears to be unrelated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @wildintellect's suggestion:

1. I changed package sources from `qgis.org/debian` to `ubuntugis`, so my `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like

   ```
   deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
   deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
   deb     http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu trusty main
   ```
2. Next I purged qgis using `sudo apt-get --purge remove qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass`
3. Purge extraneous packages with `sudo apt-get autoremove`
4. Update repositories with `sudo apt-get update`
5. Install `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass saga` (**note** `saga` in that command).

After this, no more warning of a missing install.