# Why does Buffering in QGIS fail with this error: Argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I get this error on both `2.10` & `2.12` on two different machines running `Ubuntu 14.04` with `Python 2.7.6`.

When trying to run the fixed-distance buffer on a shapefile with polylines I get the following error:

```
QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType' See log for more details
```

With full trace-back:

```
Uncaught error while executing algorithm
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):|  
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 230, in execute|
self.processAlgorithm(progress)|
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/FixedDistanceBuffer.py", line 72, in processAlgorithm|
dissolve, segments)|
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Buffer.py", line 81, in buffering|    outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)|TypeError: QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'|
```

The first time I opened the "Processing" log to see more about this error, I noticed a problem with the [SAGA installation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171264/qgis-2-12-ubuntu-14-04-saga-installation-not-found) but fixing that doesn't seem to solve this problem.

Comment: Try to print objects as thay are passed to `QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry)` to find out what causes that error.

Comment: Tell me more, how do I go about this?

Comment: Maybe @SS_Rebelious was thinking to insert a line like `print(outGeom.exportToWkt())` in your script before the problematic line and so you can see more easily what specific feature/geometry caused the problem. Anyway, seen your error message, and as @Jan Šimbera suggested, it looks like an empty geometry / like if your object `outGeom` isn't a `QgsGeometry` but just contain a *None* (which could result from a previous processing which haven't yield a geometry for this feature). Sorry, many speculations in my comment !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have a feature with empty geometry in the input shapefile. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/how-to-select-features-with-null-geometry-from-shapefiles) provides a way to get rid of them.

Comment: Just a thought, but about the answer you suggested (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/74558/53915), if the layer has many features and not so many empty geometry i guess it may could be less costly to put the problematic line (like `outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)` for the OP) between a try - except statement like ```try: outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)  
except TypeError: pass``` than testing each geometry against a `if` condition.

Comment: I provided an alternate answer to that question, since it seems one of the things the original asker tried now works in 2.12. It is possible to use the `Select by expression` function to select null geometries.