# Linux Mint: QGIS won't install

Tags: qgis, installation, linux-mint

Linux Mint 17.2.
After trying to reinstall QGIS through various processes referred to on SE, AskUbuntu & anywhere else*, I get various unmet dependency or held broken packages  errors.

Even with adjusting the repository details from saucy or xenial to trusty etc, I still can't get anywhere.

I have had this message a number of times:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 qgis : Depends: qgis-providers (= 2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
```

I can't find out what this means to rectify it - anything I've followed up hasn't worked.

I am trying to install QGIS 2.18 with GRASS.

Can someone help?

*eg:
[Broken packages and unmet dependency installation QGIS, PostgreSQL and postgis Ubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217727/broken-packages-and-unmet-dependency-installation-qgis-postgresql-and-postgis-u/223116#223116)

[QGIS install on Ubuntu 14.04 fails](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126673/qgis-install-on-ubuntu-14-04-fails)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/351899/qgis-quantum-gis-install-fails-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+index?field.series_filter=trusty, the QGIS package you have loaded is from the ubuntugis unstable ppa. This version is slightly outdated by now.

If you use the [qgis.org/ubuntugis](http://qgis.org/ubuntugis/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages) repo, you can have the latest QGIS 2.18.4 by adding to your repo list:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis trusty main
```

If you want to stick to the LTR version, [qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr](http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages) offers now QGIS 2.14.12 by adding

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr trusty main
```

In any case, stick to the Ubuntu dist version you are running (i.e. trusty), and update and upgrade all other packages **before** updating QGIS with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You might as well have to upgrade the keys for QGIS and ubuntugis.

If you decide to switch from ubuntugis to non-ubuntugis repos, make sure to clean **and** purge anything related to QGIS.

Comment: In the end, I managed to purge enough to make it work.  As a lot of people have this problem, is there nowhere to put  a guide to uninstalling what you've already got? (ideally on the QGIS site with the installation instructions) as the official instructions don't cover this just "Please remove all the QGIS and GRASS packages you may have installed from other repositories before doing the update." - the purge commands would be helpful.

Comment: GRASS tools are showing & GRASS 7 shows as activated in the Providers menu but I get the "Missing dependency, GRASS isn't configured properly" message.  How do I configure it properly?

Comment: @user3418765 this is worth a new question, adding some more details. Can you run GRASS without QGIS? Did you run GRASS or GRASS7 algorithms? The first would expect GRASS v6.

Answer (score 5):

Got this problem a long time ago on Ubuntu.

Now I'm using Mint and I've installed QGIS without any problems with:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

# nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Edit sources list and add two lines:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
```

Update and install QGIS:

```
# apt-get update

# apt-get install qgis
```

Before you try, please purge your current QGIS installation.

Comment: How to purge?  If I run "sudo apt-get purge qgis"
 , I get "Package 'qgis' is not installed, so not removed" Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have it, so you don't need to purge.

Comment: I'm still on trusty, so i should edit ubuntugis **xenial**  main to trusty?

Comment: No, leave it with xenial.

Comment: That might be it. The QGIS instructions suggest to me that you put your current version in thus `deb *repository* *codename* main`

Comment: ...or not.  Just got `The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-2 but it is not installable
        Depends: libgsl2 but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-analysis2.18.4 but it is not going to be installed
   etc etc
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:2.18.4+24xenial-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: How attached are you to your Ubuntu install? Might be time to reinstall.

That said, I think you _should_ be using Trusty if your core OS is Trusty. You should be able to remove all your repos and do 'apt-get -f install' to get to a clean place.

Comment: Not overly attached- I tend not to upgrade things unless pushed.  If I reinstall, I'll have to go through the XAMPP/localhost setup which caused me a load of grief last week (actually caused this situation). As well as all the comforts one accrues.  What does `-f install` do?

Comment: Finally worked, using `add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable then apt-get update 

# apt-get install qgis  apt-get update

# apt-get install qgis apt-get update

# apt-get install qgis  sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
`

Comment: You ran into `gdal-abi-2-1-2 but it is not installable` because that is only available for xenial. Trusty is still at gdal-abi-2-1-0. You might need to upgrade GDAL before installing QGIS.